# angularjs view not updating while model changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I am working on angularjs project now.

I would like to create custom check box filter and pass data source and selected id list from controller.

The model in view should be updated While check box has been selected or unselected, but it does not work.

```
<div ng-controller="CheckboxCtrl as vm">
  <div os-checkbox-filter data-source="vm.categoryList" 
     data-selected-checkbox-id-list="vm.selectedCategoryIdList">
  </div>
<div>
  --------------------------------
</div>  

<div ng-repeat='p in vm.filteredPerson'>
    {{p.name}}  {{p.roleId}}
</div>
```

My Plunker for [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/A5lg8XepLUI2K2dE1NHe?p=preview)

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Hi wade, you'll probably need to include some code and improve the formatting of your question in order to receive any attention on SO. Please read [ask] to understand how to format your question.

Comment: Hi Shaohao Lin. Thanks for your editing of my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepare to facepalm yourself:

`vm.filterByCategoryId` < This doesn't exist. Change it to: `filterByCategoryId`

Comment: @WadeREN if this solves your problem, you can thank hankscorpio by accepting this as the answer. Please provide reputation for his time